# Modulus of Convexity of a Direct Sum

Tags: banach-spaces

I'm looking for a result of the following form: Suppose that $B_1,\dots$ are Banach spaces such that $B_i$ have modulus of convexity $\delta_i$. What is the modulus of convexity of the space $B = (\oplus B_i)_2$? In my specific example, I have that $\delta_i(\epsilon)$ are decreasing and strictly bounded away from zero (indeed, I'm taking $L_{p_i}$ so have some very specific formulae for the moduli with $p_i$ bounded in some $[\alpha,\beta]$ with $1 < \alpha < \beta < \infty$ .)

The general idea I have is that since $\delta_H(\epsilon)$ is the smallest possible value for the modulus of convexity, it should be that $\delta_B(\epsilon) = \inf \delta_i(\epsilon)$. This is probably not true, however I imagine that there is some bound based on the moduli of convexity of the factor spaces.

I've been looking for a result of this type for a while, the paper "Uniform convexity in function spaces" by Israel Halperin and "Some More Uniformly Convex Spaces" by Mahlon Day are places where it is shown that the relevant space *is* uniformly convex.

Does anyone have a specific reference? I am interested in an exact bound, in the application I have in mind, I don't think an isomorphic characterization (ie, in terms of p-convexity/concavity of the Banach lattice) is enough.

Comment: For starters, is it clear what the modulus is if all the summands were the same space, i.e., $\ell_2(B)$ for some $B$? I suppose moduli will be equivalent.

Comment: If you take $p_i$'s decrease to 1, then the resulting direct sum of $L_{p_i}$ won't be uniformly convex. You might be misquoting the papers you mention.

Comment: Figiel, T.
On the moduli of convexity and smoothness. 
Studia Math. 56 (1976), no. 2, 121–155.

Comment: Zachariades, Theodossios(GR-UATH)
On ℓψ spaces and infinite ψ-direct sums of Banach space. (English summary) 
Rocky Mountain J. Math. 41 (2011), no. 3, 971–997.

Comment: @BunyaminSari I was taking $p_i$ bounded away from 1 and $\infty$, I'll edit the question to reflect this. It is also not clear what the modulus is if they were all the same space, but the first paper Bill links gives the example.

Comment: @BillJohnson Thank you very much, those have what I need in them!